# how to extract with sscanf using regex? (in C)

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I have the string `"pid:8792 byr:2000 cols:hkjdp\n"` and I only want to extract the number after the `byr:`. I thought that it could be done with extracting a formatted string with `sscanf(str,"byr:%d",&number);`. But unfortunately you can't do that since there are other characters before and after the number so I saw that you could use some sort of regex like in this question asked [How to use regex in sscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483075/input-using-sscanf-with-regular-expression)

so I tried something like this: `sscanf(passport, "%*[^byr:]:%[^\h]%*[^\n]", byr);` where byr is now defined as `char *byr;`. But you can't use regular regex expressions like `\h`for whitespace for example.
Long Story short: Is there any way for me to parse many strings using `sscanf` and always extract that number after `byr:` and where can I find a cheatsheet for all those characters to use in a formatted string? (Of course I know about the obvious `%f %d %s %c`and so on but  these dont really do much in this case.

Comment: Maybe you need a proper regular expression library?

Comment: Or just use other means? Such as `strstr` followed with `strtoul`

Comment: You could use `sscanf` and a format like `"pid:%*d byr:%d cols:%*s"`.  A `*` in a scanf format string like that means "scan, but don't assign to anything".

Comment: But no, `scanf` does not and cannot do true regular expressions, as [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483075/input-using-sscanf-with-regular-expression) explains.

Comment: `man scanf` contains a complete description of `scanf` conversion specifications. You won't find regular expressions there because scanf does not do regular expressions. In C, escape sequences like `\n` are turned into the corresponding character by the compiler, long before a function like `scanf` is actually executed. In a scanf format string, whitespace characters are treated identically, as described in `man scanf`; they match any sequence of whitespace characters in the input. (In most regex libraries, whitespace is `\s`, not `\h`. But neither of those are valid C escape sequences.)

Comment: @tadman but how do you save a matching regex expression in a variable? I've just seen regexes in c which determine a match or not and return true or false. What libraries are there?

Comment: @SteveSummit can I also just do something like ```"%*s byr:%d %*s"```? Because this would mean that it basically scans everything but only saves byr in a variable. The thing is does %*s also include ```\n``` ?

Comment: @Phil Not in general.  `%*s` will scan up to the first whitespace, which would work in this case, but not others.

Comment: @Phil My recommendation is the same as Eugene's.  Please read a line using `fgets`, and then search for "byr:" with `strstr`.  I don't believe it's worth trying to do it with `scanf`.  For just about any input-parsing problem you have, doing it using `scanf` is either (a) impossible or (b) five times harder, and less reliable, than doing it some other way.  See [What can I use for input conversion instead of scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/)

Comment: @Phil Or if there's a reason you simply have to use scanf, meaning that my recommendations to the contrary are not helpful, I apologize.

Comment: @SteveSummit thank you for the answers. The thing is that I have to do this on many different strings thats why I think strstr won't help here. Because the data being searched for is always different but have to get the number after ```byr:```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is not well-suited to this situation.  It does not provide anything like the general-purpose regexp support you'd need.

If all you care about is the "`byr:`" part, a completely different approach is to use `strstr` to search for that specific string.  Here is an example:

```
char *str = "pid:8792 byr:2000 cols:hkjdp\n";
char *tag = "byr:";
char *p = strstr(str, tag);
if(p != NULL) {
    int n = atoi(p + strlen(tag));
    printf("%s %d\n", tag, n);
}

str = "pid:8792 uid:412 byr:3000 cols:etfvq\n";
p = strstr(str, tag);
if(p != NULL) {
    int n = atoi(p + strlen(tag));
    printf("%s %d\n", tag, n);
}

tag = "uid:";
p = strstr(str, tag);
if(p != NULL) {
    int n = atoi(p + strlen(tag));
    printf("%s %d\n", tag, n);
}
```

Normally, `atoi` is disrecommended, because it quietly ignores trailing garbage, but here that's just what you want.

One drawback of this technique is that it would wrongly find, say, an "`abyr:`" tag.

Comment: Seems to do the trick but I have one question: Why does `atoi(p + strlen);` only include the number? Shouldn't the pointer now be at the beginning of the number and then read until `\n` is found? Or does `atoi()` only read until the next non-number element?

Comment: @Phil: That's correct; that's what I was alluding to when I said it "quietly ignores trailing garbage, but here that's just what you want".

Comment: Got it . Thank for the help